# Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token for new line

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to print the string of a PHP variable in a Javascript function.Whenever i use a new line in the string that is stored in the PHP variable, I get this error Uncaught SyntaxError while printing it out in a Javascript function.

[image]

Comment: Do not post [pictures](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Paste your code here instead, and show us what you have tried.

Comment: ok sir. i am new in stackoverflow.next time i will paste my code.Thanks

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you want to declare a string variable across multiple lines, you could use this syntax:

```
var str = `line 1
  line 2
  line 3`;
```

Note the (`) instead of (")/(') double or single quotes. They can't be used to declare multiline string.

Essentially, you will need to write it like this:

```
jQuery("body").replaceWith(`<?php echo $PHPVARIABLE?>`)
```

Comment: Perfectly fixed my issue of taking user input from a textarea!  Thank you!